# Every GET request method works but the last one won't work, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose

**The very last GET request method here is the only one that isn't returning anything. I console log to see if something is going through but nothing is even being logged to the console.**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Golf.find({Year: {$gte: 2021}, "Title": "Corales Puntacana Resort & Club Championship"})
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no scores found'}))
})

//Get data of each player in specific tournament
router.get('/:year/:tournament', function(req, res) {
    let tourny = decodeURI(req.params.tournament)
    let yearly = parseInt(req.params.year)
    Golf.find({Year: yearly, "Title": tourny})
      .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no scores found'}))
})

//Get years
router.get('/getyears', function(req, res) {
  Golf.find().distinct("Year")
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no years found'}))
})

//Get tournaments in a year
router.get('/:year', function(req, res) {
  let yearly = parseInt(req.params.year)
  Golf.find({Year: yearly}).distinct("Title")
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no years found'}))
})

//Get player names in a specific tournament
router.get('/player/:year/:tournament', function(req, res) {
  let tourny = decodeURI(req.params.tournament)
  let yearly = parseInt(req.params.year)
  Golf.find({Year: yearly, "Title": tourny}).distinct("Name")
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no scores found'}))
})

//Get all player's performances in database
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
  let person = decodeURI(req.params.name)
  console.log(person)
  Golf.find({"Name": person})
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no person found'}))
})
```

This is the GET request method that doesn't work.

```
//Get all player's performances in database
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
  let person = decodeURI(req.params.name)
  console.log(person)
  Golf.find({"Name": person})
    .then(info => res.status(200).json(info))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({msg: 'no person found'}))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two route definitions match the exact same routes:

```
router.get('/:year', ...);
router.get('/:name', ...);
```

So, any single top level path element will get matched by the first the `/:year` route and the `/:name` route will never get a chance to match any routes.

You need to change your URL design so you don't have this conflict.  Or, if the `:year` is supposed to be only numeric years, then use a more specific regex in the route definition that only matches years, not everything.

FYI, top level wildcards in routes that match any top level path are generally a problematic design because they really, really limit your ability to add new top level route handlers in the future since something like `router.get('/:year', ...);` already matches everything that has just a top level path.

Comment: I noticed that and changed 

`router.get('/:name', ...);` 

to 

`router.get('/stat/:name', ...);`

but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: @merenik -  What do you mean, "it doesn't seem to help"?  If you send a request for `/stat/John`, exactly what happens?  Did you restart your server after making the change?  Doesn't work or doesn't help does not help us help you at all.  We need to know exactly what does happen?  What do you get back from that request?

Comment: I restarted the server and sent a request for `/stat/John/` and nothing came up, not even on the console for the console log.

Comment: @merenik - `/stat/John` appears to also match `router.get('/:year/:tournament', ...)`.  As I said, top level wildcards that match anything are really a problem.  You should probably get rid of all of them.

Comment: why do `router.get('/:year, ...)` and `router.get('/getyears, ...)` both work then? Don't they match?

Comment: @merenik - `router.get('/getyears', ...)` is not a wildcard and it comes first. So, it gets first crack at `/getyears` and it only matches that one, letting all the others go on through. Routes are processed in the order you register them and the first one that matches grabs it (unless it calls `next()` to let routing continue). Again, I suggest you redesign your URL structure so you aren't using top level wildcards that match everything anywhere.  For things like a `/:year`, you could use a regex in your route definition that would only match four digits and would let everything else through.

Comment: I see. So I moved the `router.get('/stat/:name', ...)` above the `router.get('/:year/:tournament', ...)`. And they both work now. Is that because `router.get('/stat/:name', ...)' doesn't start with a wildcard like `router.get('/:year/:tournament', ...)` does?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look more into it. Is there some recommended URL structure I should follow ?

Comment: @merenik - URL structure is essentially like designing your http API.  There is no single right answer because it depends upon the breadth of what you need to design for and how much extensibility you want.  But, top level wildcards that match everything create route conflicts and remove all future flexibility so they are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

There are two link params on the same route path however their names are different but they are on same root route that's why only first request function is get executed(**ex:router.get(':year',..);**).

**this is the problem**

```
router.get(':year',...);
router.get('/:name',...);
```

so here is the quick fix

**you can change the root route for year or for name
example:**

```
router.get('/year/:year',...);
router.get('/:name',...);
```

or

```
router.get('/:year',...);
router.get('name/:name',...);
```

thankyou.